# Update session variables in PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables

I'm making a basic profile page that checks if a user is logged in, if they are not then it creates a quick email / password form, once they submit the form processes through again but sets the Session variables and displays a simple hello to the user confirming that it works.

The problem I have is that it is not working, it just returns the form rather than the logged in page. I can't see where this is going wrong and why it won't accept the new session variables. I've tried destroying the current session (which should not exist) and opening a new one... I'm at a loss.

Here's my code:

```
// session started at the top of the document

if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid'] != '') {
$name = $_SESSION['fname'];
$loggedin = TRUE;
}else{
$loggedin = FALSE;

// if the form is submitted then process the form and create session variables
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = sanitizestring($_POST['email']);
    $pword = sanitizestring($_POST['pword']);

    if (isset($email) && $email !='') {
        if(isset($pword) && $pword !=''){

// connect to database and check credentials against whats stored - all works fine
        { 
            // If password matches then we direct them to their profile
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id_login'];
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $user['name_login'];
        }else{
            $error = "email and password did not match";
        }// end check password
    }else{
        $error = 'You have not entered your password';
    }
}else{
    $error = 'You have not provided an email';
} //end if email is set
}// end if submitted

}// end if Session is set

if ($loggedin != TRUE) {

?>
<div id="login">
<form action="#" method="Post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for"email">Email</label></td>
            <td><label for="pword">Password</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="email" name="email"></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pword"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
/// display $error messages here
<?php
}

}else{
echo "hello ".$name;
}// end if user is logged in

session_destroy();

?>
```

I've messed about with the code here, moving the submit code around trying to make sure it run correctly but I just can not see where this is going wrong.

The goal being that if the user was not logged in, they are prompted to the form, once they submit the form it reverts back to the profile page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Too many syntax errors in the code. Check it!

Comment: Also, do a var_dump($_SESSION); or print_r($_SESSION) to check whether the session is actually destroyed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that your sessions are actually working? Just do a small test page:

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION["test"];
$_SESSION["test"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

You may also need to do `session_start()` depending on your PHP configuration.

This should show you the datetime of your previous call to the page if called multiple times.

---

Also, your code shows that you mix normal unparsed HTML with PHP code in your code. Make sure all changes to your session data are done before you do any output. PHP can't store your session data after any output.

---

Also, do not destroy your session. This will of course kill any session data. Just remove this line. You only want to do this if you are logging out and want to purge any stored session data.

Comment: Thanks @ToBe, I've removed the destroy session and this seems to work as far as storing the session data, but for some reason you have to enter your username and password twice before it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this snippet is in an iframe somewhere and you check again if logged in when your first login attempt wasnt finished yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the `$loggedin == TRUE` when the user is verified. Like After these line

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id_login'];
$_SESSION['fname'] = $user['name_login'];
```

add the line:

```
$loggedin == TRUE;
```

so the block looks like:

```
 if(isset($pword) && $pword !=''){

  // connect to database and check credentials against whats stored - all works fine
    { 
        // If password matches then we direct them to their profile
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id_login'];
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $user['name_login'];
        $loggedin == true;
    }else{
    ........(Rest of the code)
```